# archived .deb file error-specified file is not found using dpkg

Tags: package-management, updates, software-center, dpkg

i think my problem may be simpler than i am making it, but i am still learning linux servers the hard way.

i cannot install or update packages, and i managed to track it to an archived version of the linux kernal, or that is what it looks like.

i attempted to fix through the software center (i installed a GUI desktop for easier management option) and attempted to use 'sudo dpkg -p' with the file, the software center failed, dpkg was unable to locate the file specified, but i copied the name exactly from the error prompt in terminal

file name is:
linux-image-3.16.0-49-generic_3.16.0-49.65-14.04.1_amd64.deb

is there another way to fix this without potentially losing all information on the system, i use this for a family server and would prefer to keep all of our info on it, though if no other option the information is recoverable.

Comment: `sudo apt-get update` and then `sudo apt-get upgrade` should do most of the updates you need...

Answer (score 1):

What is the reason for attempting to install **linux-image-3.16.0-49-generic_3.16.0-49.65-14.04.1_amd64.deb** manually?

If you're trying to update your system, please try the following commands. Aptitude is really good at fixing issues:
`sudo aptitude update`
`sudo aptitude upgrade`

Another method is to use **apt-get**:
`sudo apt-get update`
`sudo apt-get upgrade`

Comment: I am actually trying to install openssh, but i keep getting an error when i try to repair that file is specified in the output, supposedly it was already installed previously

Comment: Please copy and paste the commands you executed and their output. Also, what version of Ubuntu are you using? And, how did you go with the aptitude commands i mentioned?

Answer (score 0):

As you said in your question

> … and attempted to use 'sudo dpkg -p' with the file, the software center failed, dpkg was unable to locate the file specified, but i copied the name exactly from the error prompt in terminal …

the command

```
dpkg -P
```

uses the package name and **not** the file name. The package name of the file

```
linux-image-3.16.0-49-generic_3.16.0-49.65-14.04.1_amd64.deb
```

is

```
linux-image-3.16.0-49-generic
```

or in other words, the part left of the first occurrence of `_`. For this reason, the correct command is

```
sudo dpkg -P linux-image-3.16.0-49-generic
```